# AS3 bitmapdata send to server picture is small in upperleft corner

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

Hope that the title of this post is somewhat clear. The image that I find in the folder has the proper dimensions but the actual image is in the upper left corner (small), and the rest are all white. Clearly, I'm missing some.

I have this script AS3 in place:

```
function snap()
{
  cam = Camera.getCamera();
  cam.setLoopback(true);
  cam.setMode(320, 240, 15, true);
  cam.setKeyFrameInterval(10);
  cam.setQuality(0,80);
  webcam.attachCamera(cam);         
  trace ('verzendt!!!');            
  var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(320, 240);
  bitmapData.draw(webcam);          
  var tojpg:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder();
  var byteArray:ByteArray = tojpg.encode(bitmapData);
  var sendHeader:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type","application/octet-stream"); 
  var sendReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://mydomain/upload.php");
  sendReq.requestHeaders.push(sendHeader);
  sendReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
  sendReq.data = byteArray; 
  var sendLoader:URLLoader;
  sendLoader = new URLLoader();
  sendLoader.load(sendReq);
}
```

The receiving php:

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$result = file_put_contents($folder, $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right!

```
    var trans:Matrix = new Matrix();
    trans.scale(3, 3); 
    bitmapData.draw(v, trans );
```